# How to validate XML with XSD in Delphi without using MSXML?

Tags: delphi, xsd

How do you validate XML with XSD in Delphi without using MSXML?
I am limited to MSXML3 which can't do XSD. 
Googling gave me little to nothing at all. 
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: What version of Delphi do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no non-MSXML XML library supporting XSD.

But there are some, which support DTD (e.g. [Open XML](http://philo.de/xml/downloads.shtml)). 
Maybe you can rewrite your schema to DTD, even if DTD is less powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server by any chance? If so you could do through it.

Other than that you could use third party, free tools (like saxon).

I have never used/needed Delphi's one, but so, I suppose you've seen: C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\source\Win32\xml
?
(Obviously the path will likely be different as mine is Delphi 2007).

Answer (score 0):

If .Net is installed you could use the .Net XML library.